# android setrotation issue on fragment

Tags: android

I am having a problem running a simple setRotation on a linear layout that houses a fragment.
Running on a galaxy S3 and ticking disable hardware overlays in developer options makes everything work really smoothly, without it, it causes only portions of the view to be displayed in a haphazard patch type display when in landscape.

The reason i am rotating the view and adjusting its layout parameters is because there is a list that i need to have visible with the items the user has selected even during screen rotation.

the view is displayed above a camera surface.

The xml layout of the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/occasionsOptionsLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whatOccasionTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/whatstheoccasion"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/occasionTitleImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mood" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/occasionscrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/occasion_fragment"
            android:name="com.myapp.record.Occasions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/occasionaOptionsClose"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/occasionsOptionsCloseAction"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/close" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the call to rotate the view:

```
 occasionsIncluder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.occasionIncluder);
occasionsIncluder.setRotation(rotateToValue);
```

rotateToValue is a simple call to the screen orientation value in degrees.

my question is why would disabling hardware overlays cause it to actually work better, i thought this option was to make things run smoother anyway?

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** why would disabling hardware overlays cause it to actually work better?

**A:** I want to direct you to the official android documentation on [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).
It says:

`Because of the increased resources required to enable hardware acceleration, your app will consume more RAM.`

`If your application uses only standard views and Drawables, turning it on globally should not cause any adverse drawing effects. However, because hardware acceleration is not supported for all of the 2D drawing operations, turning it on might affect some of your applications that use custom views or drawing calls. Problems usually manifest themselves as invisible elements, exceptions, or`**wrongly rendered pixels**.

`To remedy this, Android gives you the option to enable or disable hardware acceleration at the following levels:`

- Application
- Activity
- Window
- View

Hope this helps you understand the cause.For more, you can read through the link.

Comment: Shobhit thanks for the answer.

I looked through this earlier and went through the motions in the manifest with android:hardwareAccelerated="true" and false.
nothing helped.

The only way i can get it to work correctly is to have the option ticked in the developer options as mentioned in my post.
It's a brand new phone bought today, my old S3 packed up.

Comment: Your welcome buddy! You were trying to enable hardware acceleration at which level?

Comment: Well i basically worked by way from application to activity, to view.
everything checks out ok right up until i call .setRotation on the view and it goes pear shaped.

am i approaching this the wrong way here? 3am and clueless!

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the relevant section of Manifest file into the question. If your application does not behave properly with hardware acceleration turned on globally, you can just turn it on for this individual activity.

Comment: Hi Shobhit

After alot of digging i finally stripped everything out until i just had the surfaceview and the linearlayout i was rotating. it appears to be a problem when the surfaceview is changed. if i add this:
    myFrameLayout.addView(new View(this));

Its the closest i can get to getting things running ok on the animated view, but as soon as i remove the empty view or set it to GONE, everything goes haywire.

i found this in a number of places but here is an exmaple:
[link](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2011/05/avoiding-clipping-when-animating-view.html) 

Assistance much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

setWillNotDraw() was the culprit